# Does internally reflected rays count as refraction rays?

Tags: shaders

When using shders like the Glass BSDF or the Principled BSDf with transmission=1 there are rays which are reflected inside the mesh, for example in the case of total internal reflection. Are those rays then counted as reflected rays or refracted rays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are actually Glossy rays for total internal reflection.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sv2wqwsvx-8&t=224s) is a relevant talk from one of the Blender conferences.

Comment: Of course it makes sense for internal `REFLECTION` to be counted as glossy rays... By the way I looked at the video you linked and it was really good, do you have any other great sources (can be about anything modeling, shading, etc.) that you would recommend?

Comment: one thing that came to mind was this TU Wien online course on rendering https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pjc1QAI6zS0&list=PLujxSBD-JXgnGmsn7gEyN28P1DnRZG7qi - otherwise this stackexchange has been incredibly helpful to me